# when send email some styles doesn't load

Tags: html, css, gmail, sendgrid, nodemailer

I'm using sendgrid as my stmp and when I send the email, some CSS inline-styles doesn't load on the client side. What could it be?

E.g.:
Look the first div in my **source code**:
[source code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/524FW.png)

*Attention to the grid-template-rows, columns and z-index
enter code here

Now look the result that I receive in the final email:
[final email code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIJhE.png)

Simply disappear the grid-template-rows, columns and z-index (and others codes)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it's not supported.

If you check in [Can I Email](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=grid-template-rows), you'll see that Gmail does not support `grid-template-*`.